# jQuery button not executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guess I'm just having one of those days where simple things will hamper my production. So I click a button and a mask div fades in with a form on top. I click the cancel button and it *should* go away. However it's not. This code is very simple, it should have 0 problems. I just don't know what is going on.

```
$('#create_project').click(function () {    
    $('#create_project_div').fadeIn(300);
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
});

$('#cancel_create_project').click(function () { 
    $('#create_project_div').fadeout(300);  
    $('#mask').fadeout(300);
});
```

the top one (create project) works, the bottom one (cancel_create_project) does not.

here are the input tags for them

```
<input type="button" id="create_project" value="New Project" class="form_button">
<input value="Cancel" id="cancel_create_project" type="button" class="form_button" />
```

my first hunch was that I had another button with the id of "cancel_create_project" even though that was highly unlikely. I checked thouroughly and no buttons with that id. Then I even went ahead and changed the id to 'hjklijkeodjsn' just so there was no possibility that this would have the same id. Still nothing. So why on earth would this div load with the mask behind it but not fade out when I click the cancel button?

The buttons are in two different files, so i thought, hey maybe I'm a dummy and didn't include my .js. Nope. I did. I did this to prove it I added a button and a function to both files

```
<input type="button" value="foo" id="foo" /> 
<input value="Cancel" id="cancel_create_project" type="button" class="form_button" />
```

then this

```
$('#cancel_create_project').click(function () { 
    $('#create_project_div').fadeout(300);  
    $('#mask').fadeout(300);
});

$('#foo').click(function () {   
    alert('foo');
});
```

the foo alert shows up. So what in the world is going on here? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle for us?

Comment: I can't figure it out this way. The question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Is the button there on pageload, or did you insert it later ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a typo

Comment: I don't think this question is off topic, It was just a silly mistake. You can vote to close if you want, but I don't think it's merited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `fadeOut()` instead of `fadeout()` ...

Comment: man... like I said, its just one of those days. Thanks for the fresh eyes. I can't believe i missed that. `var i_me_mine === 'embarrassed';`